# How do I put slds-scrollable horizontal scroll at bottom of table (instead of bottom of page)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I have a lightning:datatable component which has quite a lot of columns, where we want the user to scroll horizontally.

The horizontal scrollbar is fixed to the bottom of the page. I would like to appear at the bottom of the table[image]

In the screenshot above, I want the scrollbar to appear beneath the last row of the datatable. The code for the component is below:

```
<div>
    <div class="slds-scrollable" style="height: 100%; width: 150rem;">
        <lightning:datatable
                             columns="{! v.columns }"
                             data="{! v.ExpenseList }"
                             keyField="Amount"
                             maxRowSelection="{! v.maxRowSelection }"
                             onrowselection="{! c.updateSelectedText }"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried every combination I can think of using slds-scrollable_x and slds-scrollable_y but can't seem to get the scrollbar to sit within the component (rather than the page).

I'd appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: Is it perhaps the case that the scrolling *is* on the `<div>` but your `height: 100%` is making the div fill the vertical viewport, and so the scroll bar appears at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I did finally get this working and should have updated the answer - in the end I had to remove the height attribute and remove the slds-scrollable attribute. I'll post the answer below

Answer (score 1):

here was the final component I ended up with:

```
        <div class>
            <div style="width: 2500px">
                <lightning:datatable columns="{! v.columns }"
                                     data="{! v.ExpenseList }"
                                     keyField="Amount"
                                     onrowselection="{! c.rowSelected }"
                                     onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
```